# How can I refight Faeryl in Archylte Steppe?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

The Archylte Steppe Gate seems incapable of fully resetting all story related events.
I reset it and get the initial hunter cutscene. Then the rest of the area acts as though I've defeated Faeryl even though i did a time reversal.

Is there some trick to this? If not then this is a bug, as the time reset doesn't actually reset the story of the gate so much as it just gives you one old cutscene. I've heard that all of the game guides say it's possible to refight him, so this might be a bug or maybe there's some kind of "outside the box" trick to resetting Archylte?